# How to fix dynamic variable assignment conflict in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, variable-assignment, brute-force

How do I fix the variable assignment in this Python code? So, I have this python code:

```
with open('save.data') as fp:
    save_data = [line.split(' = ') for line in fp.read().splitlines()]
with open('brute.txt') as fp:
    brute = fp.read().splitlines()
for username, password in save_data:
    if username in brute:
        break
else:
    print("didn't find the username")
```

Okay so, a quick explanation; the`save.data` is a file that contains variables of Batch-file game (such as username, hp etc...) and `brute.txt` is a file that contains "random" strings (like what seen in wordlists used for brute-force).

`save.data`:

```
username1 = PlayerName
password1 = PlayerPass
hp = 100
```

As I said before, it's a Batch-file game so, no need to quote strings.

`brute.txt`:

```
username
username1
password
password1
health
hp
```

So, when the Python code is executed, it loads the two files contents and save them into a list and then iterate through the username and password "brute" them until they match with what on `brute.txt`, and they assign themselves automatically. But, the problem is with the assignment, when i try to `print` them (the variables) this happens:

```
## We did all the previous code
...
>>> print(save_data)

[['username', 'PlayerName'], ['password', 'PlayerPass'], ['health', '100']]
>>> print("Your username is: " + username)

username
>> print("Your password is: " + password)

PlayerName
>> print("Your health is: " + hp)

NameError: name 'hp' is not defined
```

So, any idea on how to fix the assignment conflict? If you didn't understand something, kindly comment it and I will clear it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and they assign themselves automatically

This isn't a thing.  I suppose you're imagining that the pseudo-variables pseudo-defined in `save.data` will become Python variables in your program.  They won't.

Instead, parse them into a data structure and retrieve the values from the data structure.

For example,

```
with open('save.data') as fp:
    save_data = dict([line.split(' = ') for line in fp.read().splitlines()])

...

print(save_data["hp"])
```